# Difficulties with the writing window

Tags: keyboard

I have a new tablet Samsung Tab 3

My knowledge of the Android operating system is only rudimentary. But I can participate on forums and can write posts.  But now my tablet is making trouble. While writing a post the key board vanishes and refuses to show up again. Often I have to touch the screen ten times till finally the keyboard comes up, only to vanish again. I suppose it is a malfunction of my tablet,  and I have to ask for a new one, but it may be that by inexperience with Android  I make some mistakes.
Do other users of tablets with Android know of this problem?

Comment: Are you using the keyboard that came with the tablet, or a different one?

Comment: @Dan Hulme  - I use the keyboard that shows up on the screen when I touch a window for writing or for filling something in.

Comment: Is focus remaining on the text box you are typing in to? Just a thought that if focus was moving to another control (accidental screen tap perhaps?!) then the keyboard would close.